# Why My question is not constructive?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Hi I am here because of this [Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202860/what-are-the-major-differences-between-ubuntu-12-04-and-12-10-in-terms-of-securi).

I actually posted that question to know what things I can overcome If i upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10 from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS at the first time under performance but now I would like to know about security also.

Bottom Line: I know its not constructive, Thats question was just placed to know Ubuntu security and performance (Like RAM,processor by default) of Ubuntu 12.10 as compare with Ubuntu 12.04.

Decision up to The Community.

Answer (score 7):

I can't speak for the other two close-voters, but I can tell you I cast a close vote specifically because of the *'this question will likely solicit debate...or extended discussion.'* points. I think it could also have been closed as 'Not a real question' as it is quite a broad subject as well.

I'd like to learn about the security & performance benefits of upgrading too, but I would expect to have to read all the [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/QuantalQuetzal/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop) and browse the [security notices](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn). Any good answer to your question would have to be massive, too big for this site.

Comment: Ok Thank you for your explanation & Information you have provided is helpful.I think I should wait for remaining two voters , what do you say ?

Comment: No problem, though an explanation is optional. You might not get any more detail. Best to just move on and not take it too seriously. If you still have concerns try the chat room, that's worked the best for me.

Comment: Thank you brother, I will just move.I think I am done with this brother.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the reason is different. The point with this question is that it cannot be answered correctly. What I mean is that there is not really a way to determine whether an answer is corect or not, because of it's discussive nature. Therefore it does not really fit into preferred Q&A format.